# Azure DevOps 2019: Can't manage Extensions

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to manage the extensions for my devops Collection. When I go to https://{{myServer}}/tfs/_gallery/manage, there is a red banner which says that I don't have the needed permissions to manage the extensions.

I've found this documentation about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/how-to/grant-permissions?view=azure-devops-2019

It seems like I'm already in the "Project Collection Administrator" group.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi N.B., Any update, did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't resolve the problem. I still can't manage the extensions. I tried your suggestions, even checking with different browsers etc.

Comment: Can others manage the extensions?

Comment: Currently, I have the most admin rights in our team, so no..

Comment: Hi N.B. I was trying to reproduce this in our environment, but with no luck. Did this strange behavior only occurs for a specific project collection or all project collections ? If this only occur for this project collection? Suggest you give a try with restoring backed up collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by

1. navigating to the machine where Azure Devops Server is installed
2. Opening the Devops Console
3. Added myself as TFS Administrator

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the right way.

Try to log out and log in your account again from web portal .

Also clear your browser cache or directly use private mode, check if this do the trick.

Besides, you could also try to directly assign your user account to Manager role instead adding it to your collection admin group.

[image]